# Android default photo filename format

Tags: android, filenames

I have been trying to reverse engineer the timestamp on pictures taken on at Motorola Razr.
Im comfortable with UTC - GMT etc... but nothing looks like what I would expect.

The following are the filenames i am looking at.

2012-07-179518-07-5295768.jpg

2012-07-179519-29-3395516.jpg

They were taken 7/17/2012 in the afternoon Central time.

clearly the first part is the date.  leaving something like 518-07-5295768 and 519-07-3395516 to be a timestamp.

These values i cannot decode ANY ideas?